# Loop to get the dataframe, and pass it to a function

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to:

- read files and store in dataset
- store names of the dataframes in a dataframe
- loop to recover the dataframe, and pass it to a function as a dataframe

It does't work because when I retrieve the name of the dataframe, it is a str object, not a dataframe, so the calculus fails.

df_files:

```
                  dataframe                  name
0                df_bureau                bureau
1  df_previous_application  previous_application
```

Code:

```
def missing_values_table_for(df_for, name):
        mis_val_for = df_for.isnull().sum() # count null values
        -> error

for index, row in df_files.iterrows():
    missing_values_for = missing_values_table_for(dataframe, name)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't `missing_values_table_for(dataframe, name)` be `missing_values_table_for(row['dataframe'], row['name'])`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best here is working with `dictionary of Dataframe`s creating by loop names of files by `glob`:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('files/*.csv')
dfs = {f: pd.read_csv(f) for f in files}

for k, v in dfs.items():
     df = v.isnull().sum()
     print (df)
```

Comment: it is not what I require.... I need to retrieve the dataframe to iterate from df_files, then pass it to a function as a DATAFRAME object.

Comment: @DanielGarciaDeCceresHerran - then the best is create dictionary of `DataFrame`s and loop it.

Comment: that´s what I'am doing, but when I get the variable, it is a STR, not a DATAFRAME, so it fails...

Comment: @DanielGarciaDeCceresHerran - It seems your approach is wrong, can you add code for create `DataFrame`s ?